# Using Scanner class to compute average from a CSV file in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to read grade data from a .csv file and then compute the average grade. The data in the file looks like:

```
Arthur Albert,74%
Melissa Hay,72%
William Jones,85%
Rachel Lee,68%
Joshua Planner,75%
Jennifer Ranger,76%
Richard Rock,80%
Jerry Rose,80%
Dorothy Smith,76%
Jon Smith,60%
Lisa Smith,90%
Michael Stone,13%
Josephine Trenton,75%
Franklin Williams,58%
```

Other posts recommend using a CSV library to do this, but I'm determined to do this via the Scanner class. I'm having issues doing this, so I've first tried to do something simpler, which is just to print the grade total. My idea is this:

```
public class GradeAvg {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (new File("grades.csv"));

        int total = 0;
        int count = 1;

        while(scanner.hasNext()) {
            if(scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                int grade = scanner.nextInt();
                total += grade;
                count++;
            } else {
                scanner.next();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(total);
        scanner.close();
    }

}
```

What I get is 0. I'm guessing that the scanner is not finding any integers, as is. What do I do next?

Comment: Next you use a debugger or `println(grade)` to check if `nextInt()` is reading what you think it is.

Comment: It seems you want `nextInt()` to skip all other input until it finds an integer. Double-check if that is what it really does. Hint: read the JavaDoc for it.

Comment: Doesn't seem `nextInt()` is doing what I expect it to, which is as you say, skipping other input until it finds an integer. Not sure what the solution here is.

Comment: The solution is to use a CSV parser :-)   If you want to hand-roll one, you need to read the whole line yourself and find your integer in there.

Comment: Use `while (sanner.hasNextLine()) { `. Then in the loop use `total += Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine().split("\\s{0,},\\s{0,}")[1].replace("%", "")); count++;` then close the loop. Now just display results: `System.out.println("Total Number of Scores:  --> " + count); System.out.println("Total sum of all scores: --> " + total); System.out.println("Average from all scores: --> " + total / count);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ::

```
        int total = 0;
        int count = 1;

        while(scanner.hasNext()) {
            if(scanner.hasNextLine()){
                String data=scanner.nextLine();
                String numberData=data.substring(data.indexOf(",") +1);
                numberData = numberData.substring(0, numberData.indexOf("%"));              
                total=total+Integer.parseInt(numberData);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(total);
        scanner.close();
    }
```

Let me know if it helps. Not a very elegant solution but gets the job done.

Comment: Great, thank you. Works wonderfully. Easy to understand for a noob like me, too.